# Vertically Centering Contents of BottomSheet regardless of its state [Fully Expanded or Half Expanded]

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I'm trying to implement a `BottomSheet` in Android (using either `BottomSheetDialogFragment` or Jetpack's `ModalBottomSheetLayout`) that vertically centers its content depending on whether the sheet is fully or partially expanded. In both implementations, the sheet itself seems to descend past the bottom edge of the screen, so any content visible there will be hidden. The "halfway" mark on the sheet is therefore static.

In my case, I want the content to remain centered within the visible portion of the sheet, not taking into account the invisible portion (i.e., between the top of the sheet and the bottom edge of the screen). If the content is too long, it would scroll via a `ScrollView` or scrolling `WebView`, etc. This seems to be easy to accomplish in `SwiftUI` in `iOS`, but so far I haven't been able to replicate this behavior on `Android`. It seems like the layouts are simply not aware of how they're positioned within the screen's frame.

Here's an example using Jetpack that replicates the problem:

```kotlin
ModalBottomSheetLayout(
    sheetState = bottomSheetState,
    sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
    sheetContent =  {
        Column(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color(0XFF0F9D58))) {
            Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize(), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center, horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
                Text(text = "Hello world!", fontSize = 20.sp, color = Color.White)
            }
        }
    }
) {
    Text("")
}
```

Perhaps I need to "manually" measure the halfway point, but I'm not quite sure how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I realized that I also need this feature in my app, so I deleted my earlier answer as it wasn't really making any sense, but please check the updated one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps, below is a simple attempt on how to make sure the content stay in the middle as the `Sheet` is being dragged open/close, based on a `Parallax` effect.

```
val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
val density = LocalContext.current.resources.displayMetrics.density
val shDp = configuration.screenHeightDp.dp
val shPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { shDp.toPx() }
val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
    initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden
)
val sheetOffset = sheetState.offset.value

// weird parallax computation
val p1 =  shPx / density
val parallax = (p1 / shPx) / 2

// just a button to show the bottom sheet
Button(onClick = {
    if (!sheetState.isVisible) {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            sheetState.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.HalfExpanded)
        }
    }
}) {}

ModalBottomSheetLayout(
    sheetState = sheetState,
    sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
    sheetContent =  {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color(0XFF0F9D58))
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(shDp)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {

                var toOffset by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(50.dp)
                        .onGloballyPositioned {
                            val posInParent = it.positionInParent().y
                            toOffset = posInParent - (posInParent + sheetOffset)
                        }
                        .offset(y = (toOffset * parallax).dp)
                        .background(Color.Red)
                )
            }
        }
    }
) {
    Text("")
}
```

What we're aiming here is a negative value that will continuously offset the `Box` keeping it centered, so

- I specified the `Screen` `height` to the inner most `Column` composable using  the `Screen's` full height
- Have a mutable state `Float` offset
- Computed `Parallax` value using the following

  `p1 =  shPx / density`

  `parallax = (p1 / shPx) / 2`

  where `shPx` is Screen height in pixels.
- Observe `Box's` layout coordinates via its
  `onGloballyPositioned {...}` callback, and get its `y` position from its parent via `.positionInParent().y`
- Continuously compute the `offset` for the `Box` while the `sheet` is being dragged with the folowing

  `BoxOffset = (Box Y in Parent) - (Box Y in Parent + sheetOffset)` as `.dp` with the following

  `BoxOffset * parallax`

[image]

However I'm not sure if this is the better way to achieve this effect, I suspect that in every offset change, any composable starting from the `Box` down to all the composable it would contain will `re-compose`, I'm not sure though, I haven't tested this yet with such use-case and observe the layout inspector.

Comment: This does indeed solve the "vertically centering" problem. Thank you. It would also be useful to figure out how to set the height of a `Box` or similar to be exactly that of the visible portion of the sheet to achieve better scrolling behavior, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use your   **sheetState.progress.fraction**   there you will be getting values starting from zero, whenever the sheet dragged up it will increase and vice-versa.

Hope you got it!

Comment: I set `.fillMaxHeight(fraction = bottomSheetState.progress.fraction)`, which does work, but it causes all sorts of flickering when expanding or collapsing the sheet, so it's essentially unusable. Is there a trick to waiting until the sheet has transitioned before re-computing the fraction?